# Regular expression to extract values with delimiter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I want to extract values from a string containing a delimiter $ and store them in three variables. I need this for passing the values of the variables in my Jmeter script.

Input:

> "Blue Skies Airlines$630$270$12:23"

Here the delimiter is $, so I need to store the follwoing values in separate variables:

> Blue Skies Airlines, 630, 270, 12:23

Required Output:

> var1 = Blue Skies Airlines, var2 = 630, var3 = 270, var4=12:23

Please help. I am trying with various combinations, but it is not working. I just need the regular expression which I can use in JMETER which can do the above.

Comment: Can't you use split()? Here: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__split

Comment: I m new to jmeter...but where can I use this?

Comment: Could you please add some details about where and How I can use this function in my script? PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: I am sorry... but I am not familiar with jmeter.

Comment: [Where can functions and variables be used?](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#where)

Comment: the post says where NOT to use split..but does not tell where we can use it....need soem details...pls help guys

Comment: can anybody please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSR223 PostProcessor(any other post processor like Beanshell will also do). Add a JSR223 post processor choose laguage as `javascript`. Save the string to be split in a variable and add the following code in the post processor:

```
var str=vars.get("stringtosplit").toString();
var strArray = str.split("$");
vars.put("userResponse",strArray);
```

Here `stringtosplit` is the variable containing string to be split. The function will save the resulting string array in the variable `userResponse`.

Comment: Thanks Ruchit...but how to access the string variables: I used ${userResponse_g1}$...its not working..pls help

Comment: do i need to add something to the parameters to be passed section in the JSR223 post processor?

Comment: in the debug sampler I saw the response as userResponse=[Ljava.lang.String;@24f2f2

Comment: I modified the script to: var str=vars.get("inFlight").toString();
var strArray = str.split("$");
vars.put("userResponse",strArray);
String userResponse1 = Arrays.toString(userResponse); Its still not working..PLEASE HELP

Comment: You can use use ForEach controller of jmeter for variables which are array. http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller

Comment: If you are sure of the number of elements in array you can use those by index like `vars.put("firstvar",strArray[0]);` and put the 3 elements of array in three different variables.

Comment: I modified the above script to: var str=vars.get("inFlight").toString();
var strArray = str.split("$");
vars.put("firstvar",strArray[0]); and printed firstvar in a varible using ${firstvar}$...its still not working...please help...where am i going wrong?

Comment: Have tried using debug sampler? I have tested this code and i am getting correct value with debug sampler.

Comment: i also tried the same...the variable itself is not comming there...can u send me ur .jmx file: sarkar.nabojyoti@gmail.com

Comment: My JSR223 preprocessor itself is not working...i observed teh following error in the log file: jmeter.extractor.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script javax.script.ScriptException: Cannot find engine named: jscript....Ne idea why and how to remove this error?

Comment: removed the error, but its still not working...I used debug sampler and the results are:userResponse[0]=Blue Skies Airlines$630$270$12:23..i expected Blue Skies Airlines will be picked..i tried checking userResponse[1],[2]: both are undefined....pls help

Comment: it is able to split based on space/: which are also present in the input string..however i is not able to recognize $ as a delimiter...Feeling super frustrated...

Comment: SOLVED by using //$ as the delimiter

Answer (score 0):

We have to set the regex values in the following formats

```
Blue Skies Airlines\$([0-9]+)\$([0-9]+)\$(.+)
```

And get the values like the following in Jmeter

```
$1$ as 630
$2$ as 270
$3$ as 12:37
```